# docker push give me that error: "an image does not exist locally with the tag"

Tags: docker

I'm trying to push an image that is hosted in another project with that command:

```
docker login [first account with service-account]
docker pull gcr.io/xxx/xxx/xxx:1.0.0
docker login [other service-account]
docker push gcr.io/yyy/yyy/yyy:1.0.0
```

and that give me that error:
An image does not exist locally with the tag: gcr.io/yyy/yyy/yyy

How I can fix it? I altro tried to tag the image locally but has now worked

Comment: Do you want to push the same image to "other service-account" with different name/tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply tag your XXX Docker image as YYY, for example:

```sh
# Pull image XXX
docker login [first account with service-account]
docker pull gcr.io/xxx/xxx/xxx:1.0.0

# Tag it as YYY
docker tag gcr.io/xxx/xxx/xxx:1.0.0 gcr.io/yyy/yyy/yyy:1.0.0

# Push it on the other account
docker login [other service-account]
docker push gcr.io/yyy/yyy/yyy:1.0.0
```

Your command fails because Docker does not recognize that `gcr.io/yyy/yyy/yyy:1.0.0` is the same as `gcr.io/xxx/xxx/xxx:1.0.0` - you must specifically tell-it so by tagging such as above.